# In MATLAB, what is the difference between single quote and double quote?

Tags: matlab, double-quotes

For example, if I want to get an integer from user, and use input function:

```
prompt = "please input the sigma value for Gaussian filtering"
sigma = input(prompt)
```

will give an error message

while

```
prompt = 'Please input the sigma value for Gaussian filtering'
sigma = input(prompt)
```

will successfully run and get the user input.

My question is, what is the difference between "" and ''?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

While character arrays and strings are interchangeable in many ways, there are some differences.

Here is my favorite example for students:

```
>> a = ['1','2']
```

vs

```
>> b = ["1","2"]
```

The resulting `a` is the character array `'12'` while `b` is a `1x2` string array with entries `"1"` and `"2"`.

A second, hopefully even more illuminating example, is

```
>> d = sprintf("%1.2e1",3.4)
>> e = sprintf('%1.2e1',3.4)
>> d(1)
>> e(1)
```

Notice how both styles can be used in string manipulation functions such as sprintf, but the resulting arrays are `1x1` for `d` and `1xn` for `e`

Answer (score 3):

The single quote is used to define a character array.
Starting from version R2017a, double quote is used to define a String. From what I remember, it can’t be used at all before that version.
For more information you can look [here](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html).